# ko.mapping.toJSON 2 way binding doesn't seem to be working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've a html below with ko binding.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: ViewModel">
<li data-bind="text: name">                       
</li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value:id"/>
```

When I change the list the hideden field gets updated correctly.However, when I click submit button on form the POST doesn't send the newly updated
viewModel. It sends the old one that was retrieved.

When i get data from server I have use this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel)
```

Before I post I have done this:

```
ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel)
```

I've applied the correct `ko.applyBindings`. Could this be a bug with ko.Mapping or something I'm missing here?

Comment: Without seeing more code it's impossible to say what the issue is. Can you do a mockup in jsfiddle to show more code? One question, why are you even using hidden fields if you are doing a json submit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just to do:

```
ko.toJSON(viewModel);
```

I don't think you need to un-map the object before send it to JSON...

Comment: Does ko.mapping supports arrays?As JSON we getting from server contains a collection of array. I suspect the ko.mapping is not being able to have 2 way binding?

Comment: Could you please post your viewModel's code so we can get a better glympse of the situation?